# SQL Server database backup file is successfully created in a path but no such file path is available in my local machine

Tags: backup

When I tried to take backup of SQL Server database, it was successfully created in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\` but no such path is available on my local machine.

On my system I have `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` but no `\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER` inside Microsoft SQL Server folder.

My question is where it has been created? How to take that HFS `.bak` file?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your SQL Server instance existing in your local system (laptop/desktop) or in some other system (server?). If it's on server then go and look for `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\` on the server.

Comment: God! I didn't think in this way. You are exactly correct. SQL server is existing in some other server. Thanks a lot for notifying this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your SQL Server instance existing in your local system (laptop/desktop) or in some other system (server?). If it's on server then go and look for `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup` on the server